# Python: How do I return to the beginning of my game from input at the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

So I'm new to programming, and made a little game, with help from google. The first code of the game works, but I want to ask how I would add a function that asks if I want to play again, and if I say "Yes" for example, then it plays the game again, and returns to "I am thinking of a number....." or if I say "No" then it exits...

The second code is the code that doesn't work, where I tried adding a function for the game to play again, and suggested I add another while loop, but not too sure where to put it. Currently with the second code, when I guess the correct number, it just closes and doesn't ask for input.

I apologise for the dumb question, but I can't figure it out.

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print("Hello, I am your computer. What is your name?")
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print("\nHello " + myName + ", and welcome to the game! Do you want to play?")
playGame = input()

while playGame == "Yes":
    print("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20, can you guess my number?\n")

    while guessesTaken < 6:
        print("Take a guess. ")
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)

        guessesTaken += 1

        if guess < number:
            print("Your guess is too low.")

        if guess > number:
            print("Your guess is too high.")

        if guess == number:
            break

    if guess == number:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
        print("Well done " + myName + "! You guessed my number in " + guessesTaken + " guesses!")

    if guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print("Sorry " + myName + ", but you couldn't figure it out, my number was " + number)
    break

while playGame == "No":
    print("Then you opened this for nothing, goodbye")
    break
input()
```

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print("Hello, I am your computer. What is your name?")
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print("\nHello " + myName + ", and welcome to the game! Do you want to play?")
playGame = input()

while playGame == "Yes" or playAgain == "Yes":
    print("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20, can you guess my number?\n")

    while guessesTaken < 6:
        print("Take a guess. ")
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)

        guessesTaken += 1

        if guess < number:
            print("Your guess is too low.")

        if guess > number:
            print("Your guess is too high.")

        if guess == number:
            break

    if guess == number:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
        print("Well done " + myName + "! You guessed my number in " + guessesTaken + " guesses! \nWould you like to play again?")
        playAgain = input()

    if guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print("Sorry " + myName + ", but you couldn't figure it out, my number was " + number + "\nWould you like to play again?")
        playAgain = input()
    break

while playAgain == "No":
    print("Thank you for playing, goodbye")
    break

while playGame == "No":
    print("Then you opened this for nothing, goodbye")
    break
input()
```

Comment: Please share the function that you are trying to write.  Your post doesn't mention anything about "want to play again"

Comment: @richyen I added the code I want to make work, I hope you get the idea

Comment: you need another `while` loop to re-start the game.  Your current existing `while` loop only manages the number of guesses

Comment: @richyen do i nest the current ```while``` loop in the new one then?

Comment: you need to add a `while` before `if playGame == "Yes" or playAgain == "Yes":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the playing features as a function and call that in a while loop.

```
import random    


def PlayGame():
    guessesTaken = 0

    print("Hello, I am your computer. What is your name?")
    myName = input()

    number = random.randint(1, 20)
    print("\nHello " + myName + ", and welcome to the game!")
    print("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20, can you guess my number?\n")

    while guessesTaken < 6:
        print("Take a guess. ")
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)

        guessesTaken += 1

        if guess < number:
            print("Your guess is too low.")

        if guess > number:
            print("Your guess is too high.")

        if guess == number:
            break

    if guess == number:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
        print("Well done " + myName + "! You guessed my number in " + guessesTaken + " guesses!")

    if guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print("Sorry " + myName + ", but you couldn't figure it out, my number was " + number)

    print("Would you like to play again? Enter 1 for Yes and 2 for No")
    playAgain = input()
    if playAgain == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False



playing = True

while playing == True:
    playing = PlayGame()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't think of this. I appreciate it a lot! However I tested this, and when I enter 1 to play again, the application closes

Comment: @ThomasBates are you entering "1" or 1

Comment: @ThomasBates added fix.  Donn't forget to mark it as answered if it resolved your issue.